# displaying categories from database show empty result

Tags: php, mysql

I got 3 tables, products, categories, and prod_cat
the id of products and the id of categories are related to the prod_cat id_cat and id_prod.

i want to display the products of a certain category to show it, so i wrote this code:

```
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT products.id, products.product_name, products_cat.prod_id FROM products
INNER JOIN products_cat ON products.id=products_cat.prod_id ORDER BY products.id");
$catCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $prod_list .= "category ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> <br />";
```

but when i display the prod_list variable on the page it is empty, what did i do wrong ???

btw, i want to display like that: www.mydomain.com/show.php?cat=x

Comment: What does `$catCount` say? You did not use `$cat`.

Comment: are you sure you are getting > 0 results. echo $catCount.

Comment: try to declare `$prod_list`above the `while` loop: `$prod_list = '';`

Comment: I don't understand. "www.mydomain.com/show.php?cat=x" doesn't look anything like "category ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> <br />", so which do you want?

Comment: i want to get the categoryid as cat=x (x=1 or x=2 etc...) from commandline and display the products from that category.

Comment: i dont know how to use $cat, thats why i am posting here

Comment: Strawberry, i added something to the SQL statement, see it plz:$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT products.id, products.product_name, products_cat.prod_id FROM products
INNER JOIN products_cat ON products.id=products_cat.prod_id where products.cat_id='$cat' ORDER BY products.id");